# C# TextBox convert numbers

Tags: c#, winforms

I have textbox that I managed to accept numbers only by `KeyPress` but I cannot make input numbers separated by commas.

```
private void inputAmount_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.'))
  {
    e.Handled = true;
    // this doesn't work
    inputAmount.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##}", e.KeyChar);
  }
}
```

**What I'm looking for is:** when user starts typing numbers in text box it separate thousands by commas while user typing.

**Any idea?**

#### Update

I've added second function `TextChanged` as following and removed `inputAmount.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##}", e.KeyChar);` line from code above.

It does add thousands separators to my input but it keeps jumping to beginning of the numbers

```
private void inputAmount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  inputAmount.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0}", double.Parse(inputAmount.Text));
}
```

[image: one]

Comment: "this doesn't work" really doesn't give us much information. What *does* it do? Or are you not actually getting to that bit of code? How far have you got in debugging this?

Comment: @JonSkeet This does my first part of concern which was only accepting numeric values (integers) in my text box, now for second part (adding thousands separator) I've added  `inputAmount.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##}", e.KeyChar);` line and it doesn't do the job, i'm newbie in this and simply looking for solution to this. that's all

Comment: @JonSkeet see my update please

Comment: Again, "it doesn't do the job" is *not* a description of what's wrong. You've asked 782 questions - you *really* should know that that's not enough information by now; you shouldn't need prompting. You've now completely changed the question... and this at least *does* provide more information, but please put more effort into asking a complete question to start with in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solved

Here is my final code that solved the issue

```
    // Only accept numbers
    private void inputAmount_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.'))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    // Add thousand separators while user typing
    private void inputAmount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputAmount.Text))
        {
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            int valueBefore = Int32.Parse(inputAmount.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
            inputAmount.Text = String.Format(culture, "{0:N0}", valueBefore);
            inputAmount.Select(inputAmount.Text.Length, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suspect this will have undesirable effects if someone moves the caret to the middle of the textbox and adds a digit though - it'll move back to the end without them expecting it to...

Answer (score 0):

Check with `int.TryParse` whether the input text is a number .
Then add the inputAmount string with the current character and convert it to the desired format.

Then place the `CaretIndex` at the end of the control with `inputAmount.SelectionStart`.

The following code shows how to do this

```
private void inputAmount_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int number = 0;
    bool success = int.TryParse(e.KeyChar.ToString(), out number);
    if (success)
    {
        string input = (inputAmount.Text + e.KeyChar).Replace(",", "");
        inputAmount.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", Convert.ToInt32(input));
        inputAmount.SelectionStart = inputAmount.Text.Length;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
 }
```